# picking out repating patterns with regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

This is for an irc quizbot. I'm trying to pick out the answers for a question.
I'm fine if there is only 1 answer, but i'm confounded by multiple answers.
Tried searching for answers to my problem, but to no avail.

For example, the format is `"A child born to two Goa'uld hosts is known as a _________*Harsisis*Harseseus*Harsesis"`

Where `*Harsisis*Harseseus*Harsesis` are the three possible answers.

I wanna pick out the question and the answers and put them into a tuple which goes into a list.

I want this to end up as `[('A child born to two Goa'uld hosts is known as a _________','Harsisis','Harseseus','Harsesis')]`

Here's what i think should be right, but it isn't working :(

```
re.findall(r'(.+)[*(.+)]+', file)
```

The solution is probably easy, but i'm fumbling.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you just need `.split()`:

```
>>> s.split('*')
    ["A child born to two Goa'uld hosts is known as a _________",
 'Harsisis',
 'Harseseus',
 'Harsesis']
```

Comment: Splendid ! That was way easier than i thought :D